# Test if a variable exists

Tags: sas, exists

I want to test if a variable exists and if it doesn't, create it.

Comment: You can't really conditionally create a variable in a DATA step. Perhaps you want to write code that checks to see whether a data set has a particular variable, and if not use a DATA step to create a new version of the data set that adds the required column and gives it some sensible default?

Comment: A better solution could be to `abort;` if the input data do not satisfy the specs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `open()`&`varnum()` functions can be used. Non-zero output from `varnum()` indicates the variable exists.

```
data try; 
    input var1 var2 var3;
    datalines;
    7 2 2
    5 5 3
    7 2 7
; 

data try2; 
    set try;
    if _n_ = 1 then do; 
        dsid=open('try'); 
        if varnum(dsid,'var4') = 0 then var4 = .; 
        rc=close(dsid);
    end;
    drop rc dsid;    
run;
```

Comment: Don't forget to  `close()` your data set after you open it with the `open()` function.

Comment: The open and varnum aren't necessary here are they? Can't you just say "data try2; var4=.; set try;". In the example given it will do the open and varnum on every iteration, rather inefficent, so they should at least be guarded by "if _N_=1 then".

Comment: I need to test that var4 exists so that if it does its content is preserved. The proposed `data try2; var4=.; set try;` would overwrite any data in a pre existing variable.

Comment: Since you are trying to do this in the same step it really no better than the other answers.  Once the compiler sees `var4` mentioned it creates it in the dataset. What happens at run time has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

```
data try2;
    set try;
    var4 = coalesce(var4,.);
run;
```

(assuming var4 is numeric)

Comment: This is good. With this you can assign any default value you want.  But for character variables you will still need to define the variable's length before using it. Even if you use it first in a `coalescec()` function call SAS will default to creating it as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `var4` to itself. The assignment will create the variable if it doesn't exist and leave the contents in place if it does.

```
data try; 
    input var1 var2 var3;
    datalines;
    7 2 2
    5 5 3
    7 2 7
; 

data try2; 
    set try; 
    var4 = var4; 
run;
```

Just remember that creating `var4` this way when it doesn't exist will use the default variable attributes, so you may need to use an explicit `attrib` statement if you require specific formatting/length etc.

Comment: This will create `var4` as a numeric variable if it was not in the input dataset.

Comment: Yes @Tom, that's why an explicit attrib statement may be needed if the default numeric, 8. formatted variable is not appropriate for the user's needs.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very late answer/comment, but this method works for me and is pretty simple (SAS 9.4). In the below example, I used missing numeric and character variables and assigned a value to the missing character variable is missing.

```
    data try; 
input var1 var2 var3;
datalines;
7 2 2
5 5 3
7 2 7
; 

    data try2; 
length var4 $20;
length var5 8;
set try; 
var4 = var4; 
if var4 = ' ' then var4 = 'Not on Source File';
run;
```

Comment: This is the same answer as the previous answer from AndyBean

Comment: Not if Muray wants to be informet of the non-existence of the variable on the intput deataset!

Comment: This `creates` the variable `var4` rather than testing if it exists. What you are testing is whether the variable (new or old) is empty or not.