# Creating a template dataset from multiple datasets with different columns

Tags: sas

Currently, I have several sets of business unit data that I'd like to put into a standard template format. Some business unit data contains columns that others don't. I would like to check if certain columns exist and then to create them if they don't. I understand that techniques to achieve similar functionality have been discussed earlier, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141455/in-sas-is-there-a-faster-way-to-create-an-empty-variable-if-it-doesnt-exist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657117/test-if-a-variable-exists). However, I was wondering if a better method exists.

My current code is:

```
data Source_Data4;
set Interm.Source_Data3;
if 0 then do;
    a="";
    b=""; 
end;
run;
```

Comment: I've edited your question to make it less subjective. Please feel free to rollback or apply your own edits if you feel I've substantially changed the meaning of your post.

Comment: I'd like to point out that for this to make any noticable difference you would need either an incredibly slow computer, or an incredibly large dataset.  And by incredibly large, I'm guessing trillions of records.  I'm guessing at that number but I'm sure someone could substantiate it.  Your time is probably better spent optimizing elsewhere.

Comment: Brilliant, much better.  Cleaning up comments now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple datasets with different columns that you want to use a template for, an excellent way to do this is something like this:

```
data want;
if 0 then set template;
set have2;
run;
```

This is far easier to code than a bunch of retain/length statements.  It accomplishes the identical results as the retain solution (it defines the PDV), with one exception; it will define lengths and formats of variables based on `template` (while retain does not affect length or format).  This may be desirable or may not be, depending on your use case.  It is very helpful when combining multiple datasets, as it provides a single point at which length/format differences can be tested for; once this step occurs, you can be confident that your various datasets are all identical in variable length/format.

Creating this dataset can be done a number of ways.  One simple way is:

```
data template;
if 0 then set have;
if 0 then set have2;
stop;
run;
```

That will create a blank dataset with `have1` order followed by any new variables from `have2`.  If that's not desired, you may want to add a RETAIN statement prior to the if 0's that draws from a data dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Using the RETAIN statement should be the fastest and easiest way to do this. If the field you are checking for is numeric then put a . instead of "".

```
data Source_Data4;
set Interm.Source_Data3;
retain a b "";
run;
```

Comment: [`RETAIN`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm) would be the fastest given that it prevents SAS from even bothering to set the variable to empty on each iteration. Should have a nearly net-0 effect on efficiency.