# SAS if variable exist and less than 1, then do

Tags: sas

I need to write condition for Variables, which can be or be absent in my dataset.

The Expression such as "IF `Variable` with name starting with `VAR1` (a few first letters of the Name of the variable) exists and it is less than 1,  then do:  `error=error1`, else `error =0`

Is there a function for it? Or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: This is a very popular problem in SAS and it has been answered several times before. The best way to learn any programming language including SAS is to first try solving the problem yourself using the bunch of resources available on the internet before asking for help on Stackoverflow.

Please take a look at this issue, https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/How-to-know-whether-a-variable-exists-in-a-dataset/td-p/120083 it should help solve your problem.

Comment: Please post some sample data, and show what code you have tried.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657117/test-if-a-variable-exists, given that this question asks about checking for the existence of a variable name with a specified prefix (not specifying the full variable name).